# Angular ng-autocomplete how to load Data from Array of Objects

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, autocomplete

Apologies if the title isn't very self explanatory, actually I followed the example of angular autocomplete from [angular-ng-autocomplete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ng-autocomplete#usage-sample) and it works perfectly fine, I can load the data of countries and can work out the Autocomplete feature easily. However, in my original project code, I have defined an Array of Objects as follows,

```
assetDataDictionary: Array<DataDictionaryEntry> = [];
```

The **DataDictionaryEntry** has the following declaration,

```
export interface DataDictionaryEntry {
    id: string,
    text: string
}
```

**EDIT: The DataDictionaryEntry gets value from Database**

When I type in **[data]="assetDataDictionary"** inside ng-autocomplete, I do not get anything. I have been using the following code inside a **select** tag to populate a dropdown and it works perfectly fine,

```
<select id="assetId" name="id" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedAsset" (change)="getAssetValue()">
     <option *ngFor="let asset of assetDataDictionary" value="{{asset.id}}-{{asset.text}}">{{asset.text}}</option>
</select>
```

So how can I replace **let asset of assetDataDictionary** to work with **ng-autocomplete**

Hope my question makes sense and someone is able to help me out with it.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The example shows id and name (not text). Does it work if you change your data to that? Otherwise, (again - in the documentation) it looks like you can create your own template for this so you can render out item.text.

Comment: @MikeOne - if I change the data to that in the documentation (with id and name) then it works fine, I just need to point it to my own data now which is assetDataDictionary, when I point to my own, then it doesn't load anything and it just looks like a simple text input field.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only problem here is that your data has a `text` field rather than a `name` field like the autocomplete component's example.

So there are just a couple changes you need to make.

First, the component accepts a `searchKeyword` Input:

```html
<ng-autocomplete
  [data]="countries"
  [searchKeyword]="keyword" <---------
>
</ng-autocomplete>
```

That's the property name it uses to filter data.

In the example, it's set to `name`, so you need to set your component class's `keyword` property to `text` instead:

```js
export class YourAwesomeComponent {
  keyword = 'text'; // <--- ng-autocomplete's searchKeyword
}
```

Then you need to update the `#itemTemplate` so it displays your `text` property rather than the example's `name` property:

```html
<ng-template #itemTemplate let-item>
  <a [innerHTML]="item.text"></a> <--- change this from item.name to item.text
</ng-template>
```

[Here's a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-autocomplete-fpbfyx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) showing it working with those changes.